# Accessing different cells using numpy.nditer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration, series

I have the following code

```
a1 = 0.5
b0 = 3
ui_delta = np.arange(100000)
for i in range(1, ui_delta.shape[0]):
    ui_delta[i] = b0 * ui_delta[i] + a1 * ui_delta[i-1]
```

Would it be possible to generate this code using nditer or other instruction from numpy?
I am trying to accelerate the code, is quite slow with the number of values I am working with.
Thanks

Comment: You do notice that at some point you are going to have like `a1***99999` right?

Comment: `nditer` does not improve performance.

Comment: The values I took are experimental, just to make easier the routine.

Answer (score 0):

How about you use numba instead of numpy to speet things up.

```
@nb.njit
def calc():
    a1 = 0.5
    b0 = 3
    ui_delta = np.arange(n)
    for i in range(1, ui_delta.shape[0]):
        ui_delta[i] = b0 * ui_delta[i] + a1 * ui_delta[i-1]
    
    return ui_delta
calc()
```

This takes ~88.1 ms with the @nb.njit and ~393 ms without it. So it's a more than 4 times speed up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in your code you are not considering that in every loop I change ui_data.

Comment: For example: in my code results are (0,3,7,...,599976,599982,599988).  Going to the last one, 599988 = 3*99999 + 599982*0.5  (99999 is the last value of ui_data)

Comment: @ErnestoAvedilloCarretero oh sure you're totally right. I am sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: @ErnestoAvedilloCarretero I wrote a numpy version that turned out to be slower than your original one. Check out my numba version above.

Comment: @ErnestoAvedilloCarretero are you actually interested in all the values or just the last or a few ones? For my numpy version I derived a non iterative version of your formula. It is slower to use that to calculate all the values but it would be much faster if you wanted just the last one.

Comment: I will need all of them. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and more Numpy-like way would be using *array* *views*.
If you look at the procedure from a perspective of the whole array, what you are trying to do is take the array except the first item and add it to itself but without the last item. Basically you sum your array with itself but with a 1-element shift.

Numpy provides a very handy feature called *views*, that allow having a reference or a *view* to a part of an array. This means, that changing the elements in the *view* will also change the original array.

```
a1 = 0.5
b0 = 3
ui_delta = np.arange(100000)
ui_delta1 = ui_delta[1:] # choosing all but the first element
ui_delta2 = ui_delta[:-1] # all but the last element
ui_delta1[:] = b0 * ui_delta1 + a1 * ui_delta2
```

Using whole array operations not only simplifies code, but it is dramatically faster than iteration. Numpy has very efficient internal array loops that run extremely fast, because they are written in С under the hood. The bigger the array - the more significant is the efficiency gain.

Your code executes in roughly ~1 s
The code above executes in just ~0.4 ms

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.
The solution with numby, find it quite good.
On the other side, I still do not find the same results when using numpy
This is the numpy solution
array([     0,      3,      6, ..., 349989, 349992, 349996])

Using the numby solution the result is correct.
array([     0,      3,      7, ..., 599976, 599982, 599988], dtype=int64)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I see now your comments about my answer.

What I am trying to say is that the following solution using Numpy is still not OK.

```
a1 = 0.5
b0 = 3
ui_delta = np.arange(100000)
ui_delta1 =    ui_delta[1:] # choosing all but the first element    
ui_delta2 =    ui_delta[:-1] # all but the last element    
ui_delta1[:] = b0 *    ui_delta1 + a1 * ui_delta2
```

The result for this is,

array([ 0, 3, 6, ..., 349989, 349992, 349996])

When should be

array([ 0, 3, 7, ..., 599976, 599982, 599988])

Despite it, the solution using Numba is quite good.
Thanks